# Subversion: Ignore On Commit for SVN Properties

Tags: svn

So, I've decided to customize my SVN ignore settings for work that I'm doing that is very specific to my end of things, and I don't want those items to be committed to the shared repository. I do NOT want my new SVN ignore settings to be committed ever to the repository.

I want to be able to IgnoreOnCommit my SVN properties, preventing those changes from ever being committed accidentally by me, while still preserving them locally and preventing updates from changing them.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [runtime configuration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.confarea.html) rather than editing `svn:ignore` properties. See the `global-ignores` in the *Runtime Configuration Options* section.